# create a file using windows CMD and fill it with a repeated line but different value

Tags: batch-file, cmd, iteration

I would like to update wireshark decode-as file with all RTP range using a CMD command or a Batch script.

The file must contain values like this:

```
decode_as_entry: udp.port,16384,(none),RTP
decode_as_entry: udp.port,16386,(none),RTP
decode_as_entry: udp.port,16388,(none),RTP
.
.
.
decode_as_entry: udp.port,32766,(none),RTP
```

As you can see, it is cumbersome to add the lines for all the RTP range manually.

So the batch script must create a text file, and add these lines one by one until value `32766` is reached.

I understand the logic of the code, that it should contain a `FOR` loop (for iteration), and an `IF` statement (to break the loop until `32766` is reached), but I am not able to build the batch file successfully as I lack the knowledge.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Ala Shehadeh. It looks like you are well on your way. Use the command `FOR /?` to see how to use `FOR /L`. No `IF` needed. If you still have questions, copy and paste your code into the question as text.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `For /L %I In (16384,2,32766) Do @Echo decode_as_entry: udp.port,%I,(none),RTP`, and press the `[ENTER]` key. After you've seen it work, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key again, and read the usage information for the command.

Comment: @Compo, thank you so much, this helped a lot! I just appended ">> test.txt" to insert the output into a text file, which is exactly what I needed!! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The comment by Compo using `FOR /L` works. Another way to do it using PowerShell from a cmd.exe .bat file script would be:

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(16384..32766).Where({$_ %% 2 -eq 0}) |" ^
    "    ForEach-Object { """decode_as_entry: udp.port,$($_.ToString()),(none),RTP""" } |" ^
    "    Out-File -FilePath '.\test.txt' -Encoding ASCII"
```

Of course, it is easier if you could run a PowerShell console or .ps1 script file.

```
(16384..32766).Where({$_ % 2 -eq 0}) |
    ForEach-Object { "decode_as_entry: udp.port,$($_.ToString()),(none),RTP" } |
    Out-File -FilePath '.\test.txt' -Encoding ASCII
```